# Reaching the "write" and "ioctl" inside fops

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm looking at the linux source code and I'm trying to figure out the path taken when a `write` or an `ioctl` is performed on a device node. I'd like to know how exactly and where the function pointer in the fops struct is invoked. I could not find any references to the fops structure in the source code.

Could anyone give me more information on this / point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon specific subsystem. Taking filesystem as an example, we can check any of the different filesystems. Let's take FAT since that's the one I've been looking into recently. Its implementation is under `fs/fat/` directory. Running `git grep file_operations` in that directory gives us exactly what we are looking for:

```
$ git grep file_operations
dir.c:const struct file_operations fat_dir_operations = {
fat.h:extern const struct file_operations fat_dir_operations;
fat.h:extern const struct file_operations fat_file_operations;
file.c:const struct file_operations fat_file_operations = {
inode.c:                inode->i_fop = &fat_file_operations;
```

So there are two definitions of `file_operations` - one in dir.c called `fat_dir_operations` and the other in file.c called `fat_file_operations`. The names are self explanatory. Inside those files you can see implementations for `read`, `write` and `unlocked_ioctl` (which is ioctl that doesn't hold the BKL lock).

Similarly you can grep for `file_operations` for different drivers under `drivers/`. Many drivers implement them.